# $X$ metric separable then $C(X)$ separable

Tags: metric-spaces

Is it true, that if $X$ is a separable metric space, then the space of all continuous functions on $X$ with the supremum metric is also separable?

Comment: I don't think it necessarily is. Consider the discrete metric space on $\Bbb N$. Then the set of bounded continuous functions is the space of bounded sequences $\ell^{\infty}$ which, if I remember correctly, is not separable.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/118442/reference-for-x-compact-c-bx-separable-x-metric-space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider triangle-shaped function
$$
\varphi(x)=\max(1-2|x|,0)
$$ 
then for each binary sequence $s:\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1\}$ we define
$$
f_s(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty s(n)\varphi(x-n)
$$
One can show that $\{f_s:s\in\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}\}$ is uncountable set of functions with the property
$$
s'\neq s''\implies \Vert f_{s'}-f_{s''}\Vert_{C(\mathbb{R})}\geq 1
$$
This implies that $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ is not separable.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'm asking because I read answer to this question http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2008;task=show_msg;msg=1613.0002 and it seems to me that the compactness is used only to show that the base for X is countable, so separability of X should be sufficient to prove my original proposition (which you disproved), what am I missing?

Comment: @Josef: The linked post applies Stone-Weierstrass to deduce density. This theorem needs compactness for $C(X)$ or local compactness for the space $C_0(X)$ of functions vanishing at infinity. A further point you are missing is that the sup-metric is not really defined on all of $C(X)$, but on the bounded functions only.

Comment: @Martin: Aaaa, that explains it. Thanks very much. So in the case when X is compact, the proposition holds. I found it prooved also in a book by R. M. Dudley, but the proof seemed a bit more complicated. To the second remark, I think on a compact space all continuous functions must be bounded so I guess it shouldn't be a problem there, but you were right I was missing that in the more general case.  http://course.zjnu.cn/hnc/shibian/Dudley-Real-Analysis-and-Probability.pdf - Corollary 11.2.5